# There is a PaaS solution that acts like a bastion host for GCP?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to access my VM instances with NO external IP and by security purposes I don't want to open ports or allow SSH policies.

There are solutions in AWS like 'Session Manager', there is something like this in Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides Cloud Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) that allows you to connect to your VM instance that doesn't have an external IP:

> With [TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tcp-forwarding-overview), IAP can protect SSH and RDP access to your
> VMs hosted on Google Cloud. Your VM instances don't even need public
> IP addresses.

Have a look at the article [Cloud IAP enables context-aware access to VMs via SSH and RDP without bastion hosts](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/cloud-iap-enables-context-aware-access-to-vms-via-ssh-and-rdp-without-bastion-hosts) first. More details you can find in the documentation [Enabling IAP for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-compute-howto) and [Using IAP for TCP forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding#gcloud).

I've tried to follow documentation on my test project, you can find my steps below:

1. create VM instance without external IP:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone=us-central1-a --machine-type=e2-medium --subnet=default --no-address --maintenance-policy=MIGRATE --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200610 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud
   ```
2. go to Security -> Identity-Aware Proxy and enable Identity-Aware Proxy API.
3. configure GCP Firewall to enable inbound traffic from Cloud IAP:

   ```
   gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-ssh-ingress-from-iap --direction=INGRESS --action=allow --rules=tcp:22 --source-ranges=35.235.240.0/20
   ```
4. connect to VM instance via IAP tunnel:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --tunnel-through-iap --zone=us-central1-a
   Warning: Permanently added 'compute.3924477895872840881' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
   Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-1026-gcp x86_64)
   ...
   instance-1:~$
   ```

In addition, have a look at the 3rd party [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_LQYDKN28g).

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this will be the solution I am gonna use, this fits the most with our security standards :)

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my answer with a few details.